# Metaphors in and out Buddhism

Tags: philosophy, anatman

One of the questions / answers recently posted here was about "storing" mental states for later.

Of course this isn't Buddhist, in the sense that it does not literally describe a selfless person.

But it could be metaphorical, couldn't it? The idea that the mind is ***like*** a computer, even though there are dis-analogous elements to that term, there are overlaps - like the way that persons have access to the past in memory, **as if** they were "stored".

So my question is: are any of the Buddhas actual teachings only metaphorical?

Comment: Yes.  There are 2 truths; the relative and the ultimate.  Thus, some are explicitly metaphorical or practical, and some "point out" the nature of mind.

Answer (score 1):

> This city (body) is built of bones, plastered with flesh and blood;
>   within are decay and death, pride and jealousy. - [Dhp. 150]

[The Dhammapada](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/dhp/) is full of metaphors, similes and comparisons. It is a collection of sayings of the Buddha in verse form and one of the most widely read and best known Buddhist scriptures. Here's a [good article](http://www.buddhismtoday.com/english/buddha/Teachings/023-tnt-simile.htm) on that.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Dhammapada verses 153-154](http://www.tipitaka.net/tipitaka/dhp/verseload.php?verse=153):

> I, who have been seeking the builder of this house (body), failing to
>   attain Enlightenment (Bodhi nana or Sabbannuta nana) which would
>   enable me to find him, have wandered through innumerable births in
>   samsara. To be born again and again is, indeed, dukkha!
>
> Oh house-builder! You are seen, you shall build no house (for me)
>   again. All your rafters are broken, your roof-tree is destroyed. My
>   mind has reached the unconditioned (i.e., Nibbana); the end of craving
>   (Arahatta Phala) has been attained.

Who is the house builder? Does that refer to God? Click the link above to find out.